# "Invalid operands to binary expression ..." when trying to compare regex_iterators

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I have a simple couple lines of code

```
std::regex_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>
     regit (attributesStart, _curIter, _attributeRegex),
     regend(std::regex_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>);

while (regit != regend)
{
    // [...]
}
```

The compiler complains about the `while` line, saying

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::regex_iterator' and 'std::regex_iterator (*)(std::regex_iterator)')

Any idea why this is?

Comment: MVP? `regend(std::regex_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>)` does not declare an object, it declares a function. You want `regend(std::regex_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>())` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0, f(int);
    f(i);
}

int f(int) {return 0;}
```

[Is valid code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c12afe57f3c0b282). There is a block-scope function declaration of `f` inside `main`, in the same *init-declarator-list* as `i`, which is a usual `int`.

The same happens in your case, just in a more complicated manner. Here the function declared is `regend` and has a parameter of type `std::regex_iterator<..>` - you could have also deduced this by inspecting the error message. 
The problem wouldn't be solved by using `std::regex_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>()`; Then the parameter would be a pointer-to-function instead, but `regend` not a variable.
  Use uniform initialization (i.e. `{` and `}`) or double braces to avoid this.